# Intercction objects fabric.js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have two elements(rectangle, text), and when I move rentangle, the text move with the rentangle. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDfk.jpg)

After moving the rectangle, I want to select the text but I can not select it by clicking on it. How do I get the text is above the rectangle?

This is my code:

```
    canvas.on("object:moving", function () {

        //Objeto que se mueve 
        var obj = this.relatedTarget;
        var type = obj.type;
        var id = obj.id;
        var top, left;
        switch (type)
        {
            case 'rectangleElemento':
                var elementos = buscarporElementoID(mapa.mapaElementos, id);
                if (elementos.idTextoElemento != null)
                {
                    var textoElemento = canvas.item(elementos.idTextoElemento);
                    top = obj.top + 20;
                    left = obj.left + 20;
                    textoElemento.setTop(top);
                    textoElemento.setLeft(left);
                    textoElemento.bringToFront();
                    canvas.bringForward(textoElemento);

                    //canvas.br
                   // obj.bringToBack();
                   //Pendiente que se active el texto por encima
                }
                break;
            case 'textoElemento':
                var elementos = buscarporElementoIDTexto(mapa.mapaElementos, id);
                var bounds = canvas.item(elementos.idRectanguloElemento);
                if (bounds.id == elementos.idRectanguloElemento) {
                    top = bounds.get('left');
                    left = bounds.get('top');
                    obj.setCoords();
                    if (!obj.isContainedWithinObject(bounds)) {
                        obj.setTop(goodtop);
                        obj.setLeft(goodleft);
                        // canvas.renderAll();
                    } else {
                        goodtop = obj.top;
                        goodleft = obj.left;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Have you grouped the two objects to act as one or are you manipulating them separately?

I have done an older live exmple that loads an **Image(t-shirt)** and a **logo(i-text)** on it and we manipulate the text.

I have added textbox where we can update the i-text realtime and buttons to move the text up/down/left/right ,into the image element.

But first of all i create and group the two objects like this:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(myImg, function(myImg) {
    var img1 = myImg.scale(scaleFactor).set({ left: 0, top: 0 });

    var text = new fabric.Text('the_text_sample\nand more', {
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                fontSize:20,
            });

    text.set("top",myImg.height*scaleFactor-myImg.height*scaleFactor+150);
    text.set("left",myImg.width*scaleFactor/2-text.width/2);

    var group = new fabric.Group([ img1,text ], { left: 10, top: 10 });
    canvas.add(group);
console.log(canvas._objects[0]._objects[1].text);
});
```

Live example : https://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/zrazuhcq/

I hope that helps, good lick.